# 4 variables index function, with great than and less than for 2 variables

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am trying to use index match functions to determine the appropriate rate for the below table.

So for example a consumer loan that is for a person that owns property, the car is 2 years or less in age and the total loan to value ratio is less than 140% should return a value of 5.15%

[image: Table]

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: in your example, why would 4.90 not be a valid answer assuming that 110 is also a total loan to value ratio as well?  how are you distinguishing the last two column?  they both have identical headers.  Which column do you use when the ration is exactly 140%

Comment: Sheesk and here I thought that living status was alive or dead! 8)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Example]

I believe this is what you wanted...

I would use a series of nested if functions to evaluate which column of LTV I would want the value to come from.

"That is what is done in the AND( ) part. If the value is greater than the 110% and smaller than 140% let's do the Index Match on the 110% Column, Otherwise do it on the 140% Column."

You could extend this for more columns with more IFs in the false condition.

Then it is a simple INDEX match with concatenation. It searches for the three parameters all concatenated in a single range of concatenations.

Hope it helped.

Comment: I edited your answer to move the screenshot to stackexchanges account on imgur.  That way in a couple of months down the road the image does not change.  It also made the image clickable to see it in a larger format which makes it much more legible.

Comment: Thanks, new here ;)

Comment: When you are below a certain rep count you cant actually insert images I believe, but at some point you can and then live becomes easier.

Comment: The only thing I found strange about your answer, is you only provided 2 columns to search in and not 3 like in the OP's example data.  You did talk about expanding the dat if required.  I would think though that you would at least show an amount equal to the OP's question though.  your choice though.

Comment: @user2972169 - Another suggestion. Its better to include formula or code in your answer in form of text so that it can be easily copied by OP or other users.

Comment: @ForwardEd At the time I had not understood that the last column was >140, in fact I only got after I saw your "correction" so I just ignored it and mentioned it.

Comment: @user2972169 Actually I dont know if its >140.  I am making a guess currently while I await the OP's response to my question on the subject.

Comment: @Mrig if you have read JEEPED's post on posting screenshot instead of data, one person suggested to post screenshots of formulas in answer to match what OP does.  It was meant in jest but rather funny!

Comment: @ForwardEd - Screenshots are always better as POC which I guess you alsways do in all your answers but to make life easier for OP, adding formula in text form always helps.

Comment: I agree Mrig,  I am trying to find JEEPED's post currently

Answer (score 0):

Proof of Concept

[image: Proof of Concept]

In order to achieve the above I had to make a minor edit to your header to be able to distinguish between the two 140% columns.

The functions used in this answer are:

- [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df)
- [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)
- [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)
- [ROW function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROW-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d)
- [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611)

I placed the main part of the formula inside the IFERROR function as a way of dealing with things that may be out of range or when not all the input have been provided.  I then assumed that what you were basing your search on would be provided in a series of cells.  In my example I assumed the questions would be asked in the range H3 to K3 and I place the results in L3.

The main concept is centered around the INDEX function.  I specified the index range as being the height of your table and the width of the percentage rates.  Or for this example D2:F9.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$F$9,row number, column number),"Not Found")
```

That is the easy part.  That more challenging part is determining the row and column number to look in.  Lets start with the column number as it is the slightly easier of the two.  I assumed the ratio to look for, or rather the header of the column to look in would be supplied.  I basically used this equation to determine the column number:

```
=MATCH(K3,$D$1:$F$1,0)
```

which in layman's terms is which column between D and F, counting column D as 1, has the value equal to the contents of K3.  So now that there is a formula to determine the column, we can drop that into our original formula and wind up with:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$F$9,row number,MATCH(K3,$D$1:$F$1,0)),"Not Found")
```

Now we just need to determine the row number.  This is the most complex operation.  We are going to basically make a bunch of logical checks and take the first row that matches all the logical checks.  The premise here is that a logical check is either TRUE or FALSE.  In excel 0 is false an every other integer is TRUE.  So if we multiply a series of logical checks together, only the one that is true in all cases will be equal to 1.  The first logical check is the loan type.  it will be followed by the living status and then the vehicle age.

```
=(H3=$A$2:$A$9)*(I3=$B$2:$B$9)*(J3=C2:C9)
```

now if you put that into an array formula you will get a series of true false or 1/0.  We are going to use it inside an AGGREGATE function with a special feature.  The AGGREGATE function will perform array like calculation for some of its functions.  We are going to use function 15 which will do this.  We are also going to tell the aggregate function to ignore all errors, which is what the 6 does.  So in the end what we wind up doing is dividing each row number by the logical check.  If the logical check is false or 0, it will generate a Div/0! error which aggregate will choose to ignore.  In the end we wind up with a list of row which match our logical check.  We then tell the aggregate that we want the first result with the ,1.  so we wind up with a formula that looks like:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$9)/((H3=$A$2:$A$9)*(I3=$B$2:$B$9)*(J3=C2:C9)),1)
```

While this does provide us with the row number we want, we need to adjust it to make it an index number.  In order to do this you need to subtract the number of header rows.  In this case 1.  So the index row number is given by this formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$9)/((H3=$A$2:$A$9)*(I3=$B$2:$B$9)*(J3=C2:C9)),1)-1
```

And when we substitute that back into the earlier equation for the row number, we wind up with the final equation of:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$F$9,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$9)/((H3=$A$2:$A$9)*(I3=$B$2:$B$9)*(J3=C2:C9)),1)-1,MATCH(K3,$D$1:$F$1,0)),"Not Found")
```